# Does the Hulk's skin repel bullets?

Tags: marvel, the-incredible-hulk

I'm watching the *Iron Man: Armored Adventures* cartoon and the Hulk is just standing there taking bullets.  It seems like in every version I see, he can withstand a massive amount of damage.  Is his skin thick enough to repel bullets?

Answer (score 17, accepted):

**The Hulk is only as bullet-proof as the writers decide they want him to be. The general answer is, he is either completely bullet-proof or he regenerates so fast, no injury matters.**

It depends entirely on which version of the Hulk you are viewing and how each writer/editor team wants to portray the character with the range varying widely. While the Marvel Wiki lists all of the weapons the Hulk is immune to this list varies widely depending on the needs of the comic industry.

- The early Grey Hulk, for example, was not completely bullet-proof but only very large firearms could pierce his skin and even if they did, his incredible regenerative powers meant he stayed injured only for minutes.
- The Grey Hulk did not like to be shot at but was able to withstand any man-portable weapon without lasting harm. He tended to avoid tanks but was occasionally hit by a round with no lasting effects. If he was cut, he bled green and immediately regenerated.

  [image: Grey Hulk vs Wolverine]
- When the Hulk first became green and was called the Savage Hulk, he was far more resistant to human weaponry and only scientifically advanced technologies could cause any lasting injuries.
- The army began to hire specialists to create technologies that could harm the Hulk and the Leader was always developing new ways to harm him. SHIELD and Iron Man were also instrumental in helping to create new technologies to subdue/restrain the Hulk. See: [Hulkbusters](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Hulkbusters)
- His powers began to fluctuate during the periods when he led the Pantheon and had the intelligence of Bruce Banner. He lost his complete invulnerability but his regeneration was so potent he could recover from almost any level of injury in seconds. Even attacks from Wolverine, while they could cut him, healed almost instantly.

  [image: An attack by the U-man Vector strips 50% of the flesh from the Hulk's body.]

  *An attack by the U-man [Vector](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Vector_%28comics%29) strips 50% of the flesh from the Hulk's body.*
- By the time the psychic monster Onslaught was created, the Hulk's power level had risen to a level so great, he was basically invulnerable to all forms of conventional harm up to and including nuclear weaponry. He was called Worldbreaker Hulk and emitted powerful waves that were theorized to be able to actually destroy the World.
- In many of his future incarnations, he ages, but very slowly and is almost completely unable to be harmed by any means. See: [Maestro](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Maestro_%28comics%29)

What this usually means is when the Hulk becomes so invulnerable that he cannot be harmed or challenged effectively by writers, he is usually changed in some fashion to make him more vulnerable so that writers can create stories with conflict that matters. They will often:

- Remove the power of the Hulk from Banner's control, making him more vulnerable as Banner, even if the Hulk is unable to be harmed. The Hulk's earliest adventures were like this, the Hulk changed involuntarily when night fell, or when he was angered/injured.
- Change his environment so his invulnerability is reduced or negated. When he was removed from Earth, his invulnerability was significantly reduced. See: [Planet Hulk](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Planet_Hulk)
- Alter his psychology making it harder for him to make good decisions or alter his state of mind so decisions he makes are the right ones but for the wrong reasons. Banner's recent state being complete separated from the Hulk and a sociopath is an example of this state. (Incredible Hulk, vol. 4)

Comment: Thanks. I didn't know about the regeneration part of it.

Comment: You are quite welcome. Glad to be of service.

Answer (score 4):

from the [Marvel wiki](https://marvel.fandom.com/wiki/Robert_Bruce_Banner_(Earth-616))

> Superhuman Durability: In addition to great strength, the Hulk's body possesses a high degree of resistance to injury. The Hulk's skin is impervious to conventional blades, adamantium and vibranium being amongst the very few metals that are truly capable of piercing his skin. The Hulk is capable of withstanding high caliber bullets, powerful explosives, pressures extremes, falls from orbital heights [202][197], maximized heat without blistering, maximized cold without freezing, and great impacts

I'd assume that this means that conventional bullets won't penetrate the skin. However, Adamantium or Vibranium bullets could probably do it.

Answer (score 1):

In the Marvel Cinematic Universe, the answer is also yes.  In *The Avengers*, we see him shrugging off a barrage of heavy machine gun fire;  it doesn't seem to do anything but annoy him (the shooting starts at about 2:45 into the video).

Comment: Thanks for the edit, phantom42.  I couldn't figure out how to embed the video.

Comment: Yeah, embedding videos is deceptively simple.  Took me over a year to figure it out.  :P

Answer (score 0):

> Thaddeus wrote :
>
> Change his environment so his invulnerability is reduced or negated.
> When he was removed from Earth, his invulnerability was significantly
> reduced. See: Planet Hulk

I believe the obedience disc he was forced to wear is the reason his powers were limited, that is why he was known as the Green Scar, as his regeneration powers stopped working. Once the disc was removed they kicked in.

> By the time the psychic monster Onslaught was
> created, the Hulk's power level had risen to a level so great, he was
> basically invulnerable to all forms of conventional harm up to and
> including nuclear weaponry. He was called Worldbreaker Hulk and
> emitted powerful waves that were theorized to be able to actually
> destroy the World.

You've mixed up the timelines. Onslaught was about a decade before World War Hulk. I believe Hulk has always been resistant to nukes. The Worldbreaker is a persona of the Hulk that manifests himself during periods of extreme anger, when he was told of Meek's betrayal or believed Betty and Rick had been killed. In the Worldbreaker state he emits high levels of gamma energy.

Chetter Hummin see :

[image: Hulk #1 2014]