# How would the Hulk's transformation affect an artificial joint?

Tags: marvel, the-incredible-hulk

I was wondering, should the (comic book) Hulk get an artificial joint, if his transformation process would remain the same.

Can the Hulk's natural strength be retained or reproduced synthetically through an artificial joint, to the same level of perfection? Or would it, for example, be ejected from the Hulk's body when he transformed to Hulk from Dr. Banner?

How would the Hulk's transformation affect an artificial joint? And to reiterate, I'm interested in the comic book Hulk.

Comment: I would like to point out that in some fiction, the organism expels the artificial joint and grows an organic replacement. Take the recent *The Thing* prequel. In others, they might not be so careful, such as Bixby's Hulk which after becoming Banner again would suddenly shrink the waist of his 60" pants.

Comment: It might help to know which Hulk you want an answer for.  The comic book Hulk is insanely powerful; there was a Marvel-DC crossover where Hulk fought Superman.  But the TV show Hulk was much more limited.  They actually killed him off in a TV movie after the regular series ended.

Comment: Oh, I'd say the comic book Hulk in that case, definitely. Thanks -- I'll edit to clarify.

Comment: @KyleJones I'm still not convinced the TV show was about the same character. For one thing, Dr Banner's first name was David. And he never met anybody else from the Marvel universe.

Comment: @MrLister His tombstone read David Bruce Banner.  And Banner did meet one Marvel character; there was a follow-on [TV movie](http://www.imdb.com/title/tt0098512/) where he met Matt Murdock aka Daredevil.

Comment: he also met Thor. http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/The_Incredible_Hulk_Returns

Answer (score 6, accepted):

**It is unlikely the Hulk could ever use such an internal augmentation without serious consequence. This device would be a problem for the Hulk on a number of levels:**

- The Hulk would never need such a device as his regenerative powers make such internal devices obsolete. His regenerative prowess is so great he can replace a significant portion of his mass instantly.
- Even if Dr. Banner were to be fitted with such a device, his first transformation into the Hulk destroy or expel the device immediately as his normal body would replace the device with the superhuman flesh of the Hulk.
- No normal material could replace the flesh of the Hulk since his superhuman physical capabilities would be greater than any normal material. Only matter made of [adamantium](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Adamantium) or [Uru](http://marvel.wikia.com/Uru) might be able to substitute for bone-like material for the Hulk, assuming the material was not simply displaced by the Hulk's superhuman regenerative capabilities.
- It is also assumed whatever transformation creates the Hulk, it returns Banner to a normal and physically functioning state, though his mental capacity has varied upon transformation.

**Most of the physics of the Hulk's regeneration can be found in the following links:**

[Does the Hulk's skin repel bullets?](https://scifi.stackexchange.com/a/22796/2765) An excerpt follows:

- His [the Hulk's] powers began to fluctuate during the periods when he led the Pantheon and had the intelligence of Bruce Banner. He lost his complete invulnerability but his regeneration was so potent he could recover from almost any level of injury in seconds. Even attacks from Wolverine, while they could cut him, healed almost instantly.

[image: An attack by the U-man Vector strips 50% of the flesh from the Hulk's body.]

*An attack by the U-man [Vector](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Vector_%28comics%29) strips 50% of the flesh from the Hulk's body.*

- By the time the psychic monster Onslaught was created, the Hulk's power level had risen to a level so great, he was basically invulnerable to all forms of conventional harm up to and including nuclear weaponry. He was called Worldbreaker Hulk and emitted powerful waves that were theorized to be able to actually destroy the World.
- In many of his future incarnations, he ages, but very slowly and is almost completely unable to be harmed by any means. See: [Maestro](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Maestro_%28comics%29)

Comment: This is a lot of information. Can you provide canon citations for any of it? That would be great -- :)

Comment: @aSlytherin Thaddeus is likely calling on trends he's observed in the many years he's read comic books. So I'm not sure how much he can cite from 'canon'. Comic book 'canon' is not always very reliable.

Comment: Comics are difficult to canonize because different writers have different interpretations of a character. In some cases the character's abilities vary wildly. This is the cause of many of the most enduring conversations on the Internet regarding the fighting prowess of different heroes. As ammunition, readers clip scenes from stories which support their point. Such battles are entertaining but flawed because if you follow a comic series, the very next writer may contradict what a previous writer has said is true. All I am left with as a scientist is a range of possibilities.