# Can the hulk be affected by poison?

Tags: marvel

My friend and I got into an argument about which one of our favorite super heroes, Spider-man and Hulk respectively, would win in a 1 on 1. I said there is no way that Spider-Man would win and she claimed that he would just use "poison web balls" and poison the Hulk. Is that even possible? Can the Hulk be affected by poisons?

Comment: Welcome to the Science Fiction and Fantasy Stack Exchange Andy. While your question is potentially interesting we don't tend to answer general combat related questions in this format. You might want to check the Help button near the Search window to get a better idea of how to format your questions.  This is possibly answered by: [Does the Hulk's skin repel bullets?](http://scifi.stackexchange.com/questions/22793/does-the-hulks-skin-repel-bullets)

Comment: Haven't Spider-Man and the Hulk fought each other already ?

Comment: Cells regeneration would be faster than poisons damage.

Comment: @kalissar, yes - and Spidey tends to be too quick for the Hulk.

Comment: @phantom42 but I guess spidey can't hurt the Hulk ? Would love to ask the question, but that definitely sounds like a shark vs gorilla one :(

Comment: Spidey is nothing more than a costume filled with a pulsating mass of genetically altered spiders. If that doesn't just creep the hell out of the Hulk, I don't know what would. No poison needed.

Comment: This question is bizarre and completely uninformed about Spiderman. You might as well ask why Andy Warhol couldn't kill Hulk with his magical monster truck and a can of cheese whiz.

Comment: But Spider-Man doesn't carry poisoned equipment by default (unless he had it with his Level 2 powers that he lost in One More Day).

Answer (score 5, accepted):

If I remember correctly, there's an episode of the Hulk cartoon where the Hulk does, indeed, get poisoned. I odn't know if that's canon, though, even though it's an official cartoon. The plot of that episode involved the Hulk being poisoned, and his friends having to make him angry for him to burn the poison out of his system.

I don't know of any instances in the comic canon where the Hulk has been poisoned. However, judging from the cartoon, I'd say that it's possible - however, the Hulk would likely metabolize the poison from his system fairly quickly (quicker if he's angry and doing a lot of activity).

Edit: Err....I guess I misremembered the episode, but I found it here. (http://www.imdb.com/title/tt0610944/) The Hulk is actually hit with a tranquilizer - he has to burn it out of his system. As such, the Hulk may be susceptible to drugs, but he'd still be able to overcome it - additionally, there's the issue of getting it into his system in the first place (as in the episode, I think they used a "tranquilizer ray" or something weird.

Comment: From my understanding, the Hulk isn't invulnerable or really immune to anything. He just got extensive regenerative abilities (and strength and stuff), so he can be cut, crushed, poisoned, etc. but the effects are (based on what's happening) minimal to non-existant, just because his extra fast metabolism.

Comment: It has happened at least once in the comics. It was by a new super-villain that was a Banner fanboy/rival and the Leader's brother. (I think "Random" may have been his villain name.) But this wasn't a super-strong generic poison, but one custom-made by Random to target Banner/Hulk.